# Entity.HasRequired returning items with NULL property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two related entities built and linked with Fluent API.

```
public class EDeal : IEntityBase
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Customer_id { get; set; }
    public virtual ECustomer Customer { get; set; }
    ...etc
}

public class ECustomer : IEntityBase
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Customer_id { get; set; }
    public string Customer_name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EDeal> Deals { get; set; }
    ...etc
}
```

linked with

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ECustomer>().HasKey(c => c.Customer_id);
modelBuilder.Entity<EDeal>().HasRequired<ECustomer>(s => s.Customer)
    .WithMany(r => r.Deals)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.Customer_id);
```

I recognize that this is inefficient linking but I had to link it in this way because I don't have control over the db structure.

The important thing to note is that the EDeal requires an ECustomer (.HasRequired).  The database contains many rows in EDeal that have a null Customer_id field and I do not want to ever pull those lines when I query the entity.

I thought that the .HasRequired would make sure that I never got back any EDeals that do not have ECustomers associated with them but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Instead, it only seems to ignore those lines with NULL Customer_id values when I try to order by a property in the Customer.  And even then, returning the .Count() of the query behaves strangely.

```
var count1 = db.Set<EDeal>().Count(); //returns 1112
var count2 = db.Set<EDeal>().ToList().Count(); //returns 1112
var count3 = db.Set<EDeal>().OrderBy(c => c.Customer.Customer_name).Count(); //returns 1112
var count4 = db.Set<EDeal>().OrderBy(c => c.Customer.Customer_name).ToList().Count(); //returns 967
```

I know I can add a .Where(c => c.Customer.Customer_id != Null) to make sure I only get back what I'm looking for, but I'm hoping for a solution in the Entity's configuration because I have many generic functions acting on my IEntityBase class that build dynamic queries on generic Entities and I don't want to use a workaround for this case.

Questions:

1) Is there a way to limit the entity to only return those EDeals that have a corresponding ECustomer?

2) In my example above, why do count3 and count4 differ?

Thanks in advance.